# Why does my first expression evaluate to false and my second one evaluates to true? Shouldn't they be the same?

Tags: javascript

Lets say that `error.message = 'user_not_found'`

```
    console.log(
        error.message === 'user_not_found' || error.message === 'password_missing_onboarding_incomplete'
            ? false
            : true
    );
```

This returns `false` and is working good.

I tried shortening this to:

```
console.log(error.message !== 'user_not_found' || error.message !== 'password_missing_onboarding_incomplete');
```

Which I assumed would work the same, but instead it returned `true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Part of inverting a statement is changing all `||` to `&&` and vis versa. Since this is basically just an inversion, you can change the `||` to `&&` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

The negative of

```js
error.message === 'user_not_found' || error.message === 'password_missing_onboarding_incomplete'
```

is

```js
error.message !== 'user_not_found' && error.message !== 'password_missing_onboarding_incomplete'
```

Answer (score 1):

just group the logic and then negate it

```js
console.log(!(error.message === 'user_not_found' || error.message === 'password_missing_onboarding_incomplete'));
```

if it was full it would be

```js
let result = !(
    error.message === 'user_not_found' ||
    error.message === 'password_missing_onboarding_incomplete'
);
```